# Entity Framework - how can I optimize “Contains” statement?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-4

In our current application we have some performance issues with some of our queries. Usually we have something like:

```
List<int> idList = some data here…;
var query = (from a in someTable where idList.Contains(a.Id));
```

while for simple queries this is acceptable, it becomes a bottleneck when we have more items in idList (in some queries we have about 700 id’s to check, for example).

Is there any way to use something other then Contains? We are thinking of using some temporary tables to first insert the Ids, and then to execute join instead of Contains, but it would seem EntityFramework does not support such operations (creating temporary tables in code) :(

What else can we try?

Answer (score 1):

I Suggest using [LINQ PAD](http://www.linqpad.net/) it offers a "Transform to SQL" option which allows you to see your query in SQL syntax.

there is a chance that this is the optimal solution (if youre not into messy stuff).
might try holding the idList as a sorted array and have the contains method replaced with a binary search. (you can implement your own extension).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var query = someTable.Where(a => idList.Any(b => b.Id == a.Id));
```

Comment: I suspect that will produce similar if not identical SQL so I am not sure why it would be more efficient.

Comment: Why would you expect that to be faster than `Contains`?

Comment: Because Contains use a linear search; therefore, this method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having a physical table you could use a semi-temporary table.  The basic idea is:

1. Create a physical table with a "query id" column
2. Generate a unique ID (not *random*, but *unique*)
3. Insert data into the table tagging the records with the query ID
4. Pass the query id to the main query, using it to join to the link table
5. Once the query is complete, delete the temporary records

At worst if something goes wrong you will have orphaned records in the link table (which is why you use a unique query ID).

It's not the cleanest solution but it will be faster than using `Contains` if you have a lot of values to check against.

Comment: That's what we are thinking of using - still this is ugly :/ it is a shame Entity doesn't support creating some sort of temporary tables from code...

Answer (score 1):

When Entity Framework starts being a performance bottleneck, generally it's time to write actual SQL.

So what you could do for example is build a [**table-valued function**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx) that takes a **table-valued parameter** (your list of IDs) as parameter. The function would just return the result of your `JOIN`.

Table valued function feature requires EF5, so it might be not an option if you're really stuck with EF4.

Comment: If there will be no other choice, we will probably end up using some server side processing (stored procedure, or function), but this is something I would like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to refactor your queries to get rid of `idList`.

For example you should return the list of orders of male users 18-25 year, from France. If you filter users table by age, sex and country to get `idList` of users you end up with 700+ id's. Instead you make `Orders` table join with `Users` and apply filters to the `Users` table. So you don't have 2 requests (one for ids and one for orders) and it works much faster cause it can use indexes while joining the table.

Makes sense?